# How To Get An Object Value

Tags: javascript, object, vue.js, vuejs2

Consider this data:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Title one",
    "category_data": {
        "2": "Team",
        "7": "Queries"
    }
},
```

I loop through my data to all the categories using this function:

```
   remove_category_duplicates: function () {
        // Get all categories and remove duplicates
        let data = {}
        this.info.forEach(i=>{
            Object.assign(data,i.category_data);
        })

        return data;
    },
```

This returns an object, like so:

```
Object {
 12: "Fax",
 2: "Team",
 6: "Questions",
 7: "Queries"
}
```

How can I also return just the value (Ex, *Fax*)? I want to then push those name values into an array.

Thanks

Comment: [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values)

Comment: Read up on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values - it does exactly this

Comment: _Ex_ means 12 here?

Comment: Object.values isn't fully supported: https://caniuse.com/#feat=object-values. I'd suggest better to use [lodash polyfill](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#values)

Comment: @Frost no, sir. That would be "Fax". Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To return only values you can use the `Array.map` function like this:

```
let arr = this.info.map(val => val.category_data);
```

...or use the newer `Object.values()` as mentioned in the comments ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can push values by this way

```js
 var info = [{
          "id": 1,
          "title": "Title one",
          "category_data": {
            "2": "Team",
            "7": "Queries"
          }
        }];
        
        var remove_category_duplicates = function () {
          // Get all categories and remove duplicates
          let data = [];
          for (var i in info) {
            if (info[i] && info[i].category_data) {
              var category_data=info[i].category_data;
              for (var j in category_data) {
                  data.push(category_data[j]);
              }
            }
          }
          console.log(data)
          return data;
        };
        remove_category_duplicates();
```